# How to modify a theme (macbuntu)?

Tags: 16.04, themes, titlebar, ambiance, macbuntu

I want to use the theme Macbuntu. But the way this theme format the window's title bar is unacceptable (it colors the title bar greyish-white) or in other words, the readability is not legible.
I have ubuntu 16

since I am new to Ubuntu so is there a way so I can edit the Macbuntu theme and make the title bar's (top panel) color to black (the color same as in Ambiance theme)?

Comment: or I saw a tutorial on OMG Ubuntu using GNOME instead of Unity on making Ubuntu look like mac http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-5-steps

Comment: Please improve your question itself by editing it rather than add supplementary information as comments.

Comment: @DKBose that is not a supplementary information but rather a suggestion for others to read what i saw so that others can give their suggestion

Comment: I tried searching for a macbuntu package but did not find anything so I don't think this package is in the offical repositories.

Comment: @ianorlin this package is in noobslab macbuntu ppa. all i want to do is just edit the color of the title bar in this theme. i am new to ubuntu so i dont know much